# React: NextJS, do I need 2 servers for deployment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

Stumbled accross NextJS in `npm` and tried it out. Look pretty good and relatively easy to use. However, one thing about it is still not clear to me:

Suppose I want to have also have a NodeJS (or whatever) api server in complement with the server side rendering that NextJS offers. Do I need 2 server then? For example:

[image: NextJS servers deployment]

Also is NextJS just a rendering server (which can render React components and creates HTML) or something else/more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use the same server to implement your `api`.

On official documentation page about [Custom server and routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/#custom-server-and-routing) there are examples of integrating with popular `node` frameworks like `express` or `koa` - so you can use them for regular purposes.

What about `nextjs` itself - like it's said on official documentation page:

> Next.js is a minimalistic framework for server-rendered React
>   applications.

So it has not only capabilities of server side rendering, but also routing (including client one), css-in-js setup and so on.